# Spark History UI not working | Ambari | YARN

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I have a hadoop cluster setup using Ambari which has services like HDFS,YARN,spark running on the hosts.
When i run the sample spark pi in cluster mode as master yarn, the application gets successfully executed and I can view the same from resource manager logs.
[image]

But when i click on the history link, it does not show the spark history UI. How to enable/view the same?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your spark-history server is already configured by looking for `spark.yarn.historyServer.address` in *spark-defaults.conf* file.

If not configured, this link should help you configure the server: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.6/bk_installing_manually_book/content/ch19s04s01.html

If already configured, check if the history server host is accessible from all the nodes in the cluster, and also the port is open.

Comment: I can see 2 folders having spark-defauls.conf :
'/etc/spark/2.5.3.0-37/0/spark-defaults.conf'  and
'/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf'

Which ones takes precedence?

'/etc/spark/2.5.3.0-37/0/spark-defaults.conf' contains :
"spark.history.ui.port 18080
spark.yarn.historyServer.address <hostaddress>:18080"

while '/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf' contains commented out settings :
"#spark.yarn.historyServer.address   localhost:18080"
So appears its commented out? or by default these properties are active?

Comment: and the history server is accesible from all hosts...checked via ssh and telnet

Comment: So history server is running. Is the property `spark.eventLog.dir` set in that config file?

Comment: yep...
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs:///spark-history

Comment: It should be something like this: `spark.eventLog.dir="hdfs://NAME_NODE_HOST:8020/user/path-to-dir"`

Comment: what difference does it make? as by default , hortonworks does the same.
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.6/bk_installing_manually_book/content/ch19s04s01.html

Also, the directory is logging everything correctly 
/spark-history/application_1484222082388_0001_1 etc

Just the UI for the same is not accessible.