# Can't find spark-submit finished job in Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I submitted a job using `spark-submit`, the job finished correctly but it does not show in Yarn.

how can I view the process directly in Yarn ? I already specified with yarn client mode, but in yarn web console I see nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this other Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836740/yarn-application-list-doesnt-show-any-results), `yarn application -list -appStates FINISHED` might do the job. Also in this same thread, you will find another possible reason:

> It turns out that I had enabled Log aggregation in YARN but had set the **yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir** to a custom hdfs directory (/tmp/yarnlogs), So logs were actually getting aggregated at /tmp/yarnlogs in HDFS, but the yarn command was still searching for logs at the default location on HDFS (/tmp/logs). So changing the property to its default value fixed it for me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No it shows nothing, the job is not even listed in finished job list

Comment: Even in "yarn application -list -appStates ALL"?

Comment: yes there is nothing, but spark-submit finished the job with success

Comment: maybe there is something that connects spark with yarn together which i forgot ?

Comment: Are you connected to the right cluster? Is history server up? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627985/spark-history-ui-not-working-ambari-yarn

Comment: I run on local machine, so there is only 1 cluster

Comment: Updated answer with another possible reason.